# Access - Report Formatting and Display

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table with the following dates 3/2/2014, 3/5/2014, 6/21/2014, 8/16/2014, 1/5/2015. I need a way to display everyday in each month and display a Y if the date exists and a N if it does not. The table is dynamic and can have more dates added to it.

Example:

```
          March 2014
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ... | 31
N | N | Y | N | Y | ... | N
          July 2014
1 | 2 | ... | 20 | 21 | 22 | ... | 31
N | N | ... | N  | Y  | N  | ... | N
          August 2014
1 | 2 | ... | 20 | 21 | 22 | ... | 31
N | N | ... | N  | Y  | N  | ... | N
          January 2015
1 | 2 | ... | 15 | 16 | 17 | ... | 31
N | N | ... | N  | Y  | N  | ... | N
```

I am new to Access, so any help would be appreciated :)

UPDATE:
If I wanted to change the above example to where instead of returning just "Y" or "N" I now wanted to return a Project ID, how would I go about editing the IIF statement? The Project ID's are stored in the same table as the Dates.

```
          March 2014
1 | 2 |  3  | 4  | 5   | ... | 31
N | N |  4B | N  | 2W  | ... | N
          July 2014
1 | 2 | ... | 20 | 21  | 22  | ... | 31
N | N | ... | N  | Z8  | N   | ... | N
          August 2014
1 | 2 | ... | 20 | 21  | 22  | ... | 31
N | N | ... | N  | E5  | N   | ... | N
          January 2015
1 | 2 | ... | 15 | 16  | 17  | ... | 31
N | N | ... | N  | 1FF | N   | ... | N
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a CrossTab query (pivot).
Something like:

```
TRANSFORM iif(Count(*)>0,"Y","N") AS Val
SELECT Year(YourDate) AS Y, Month(YourDate) AS M
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Year(YourDate), Month(YourDate)
PIVOT Day(YourDate) In ("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. How would I be able to account for days with 30 days, February, and Leap Years?

Comment: That's a good question, Crash, but you have two ways to get your result: if you don't specify column headers list (the single days in the IN clause), you have a dynamic result; if a Day doesn't exist at all, you don't get the column. Otherwise you can specify the headers column names. So you are sure that you always have the columns. What I can suggest to you is: if you have the database full populated, with many records for every day, you can try to avoid the IN clause. Otherwise, with my poor knowledge of Access Database, I can't help you... :(

Comment: Corrado Piola, you have helped more than you know. SQL is also new to me, and this is a great start that I, or someone else, may be able to work off of :)

Comment: Thanks, Crash, it's a pleasure to help so kind people... Good luck! :)